# 404 Image Nominations

Tags: discussion, top-7, meta

All the other sites seem to be doing this...

We need an image that will be displayed when users try to bring up a page that does not exist.

Please quote the source so the team can negotiate rights if necessary.

Comment: Please keep the [Ubuntu Brand Guidelines](http://design.canonical.com/the-toolkit/ubuntu-brand-guidelines/) in mind when using the Ubuntu logo.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hi guys. 
[image]
Have a look at the proposed design and add your comments please :)

Comment: Wow. I don't know how you keep creating such awesome stuff... but keep it up!

Comment: Is there a chance that this could be used? I hope so, it's well done!

Answer (score 24):

## We couldn't find the page you were looking for...

You should talk to our new network administrator.

[image]

Source: [linux.org.uk](ftp://ftp.linux.org.uk/pub/linux/).

Answer (score 9):

Since we have a nice round logo for ubuntu & friends, why not simply make it say 4 [logo] 4.

Answer (score 3):

Another idea I had.

The entire webpage is the bottom of a book. This book has a lot of pages. The footer of the book says "Ubuntu StackExchange" (or the name of the site once that's agreed) and the page number 403 on the next "page" the same footer "Ubuntu StackExchange" and the page number 406 and an obvious tear in the binding where page "404/405" would be.

For as you can see, the page "404" couldn't be found!

Comment: this is funny!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think something more simplistic.

Giant text, that says "404" after a few seconds though the number starts increasing slowly then more rapidly until it stops at 9,001 small text under the GIANT 9,001 says simply "This page is over 9,000" then a redirect to the home page should be in order after that.

Comment: ITS OVER 90000!!!

Answer (score -2):

[image]

From [linuxowns.files.wordpress.com](http://linuxowns.wordpress.com/2008/05/15/pixelize/).

Comment: Absolutely couldn't resist!!!

Comment: -1 for obvious reasons :)

Comment: @Ressu: Well, maybe you can elaborate, because not everyone might get it.

Comment: There are a few reasons: using a picture of someone without their permission, using that same picture to promote something that they do not endorse and finally using a false quote. It's a legal case waiting to happen.

Comment: Also Mark Shuttleworth' blog about tribalism comes to mind 

    http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/439

Comment: Ya, I knew this wouldn't get picked as the 404 image - but it's funny! Feel free to delete it if needed.

Comment: No need for deletion. It would fall under parody :)

Comment: Well played george!

Answer (score -5):

[image]

From [Be the Wumpus](http://bethewumpus.sourceforge.net/).