# Finishing the Beta off strong and prepping for 10.10.

Tags: discussion

(Heavy updates)

With 10.10 on the horizon I thought I'd start looking at we need to finish off. This is an extension of Oli's original question about [steering this ship](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/261/whos-running-this-ship-and-wheres-it-going). Thanks to everyone who have made the beta a success, and now we're ready to open the doors for the rest of the world.

**The Current Status**

- Check out the [Design Thread](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/377/design-ideas-for-the-final-site)
- Barring any foreseeable problem we'll go live on 10.10, along with the distro.
- Single Sign on with login.ubuntu.com openIDs will work at launch.

**How to Help**

- We need everyone helping market the site. Let's ride the wave of release. Mention it when you tweet, when you help people on IRC, etc. Encourage people to visit and give us a shot.

  - If you're going to a release party spread the word!
- Focus on Quality. In 60-ish short days the quality of the site has been amazing, we're already showing up in google results, keep it up!

  - Clean up your questions and answers, go clarify bits, add a screenshot; attention to detail!
  - Clean up your junk comments that might not be relevant anymore (I have a ton I will be cleaning up this weekend).
  - Give the unanswered questions a shot.
  - Help stem the tide of new questions
  - Set the example for others to follow!

**The Future**

- Automagic application installation via apt.ubuntu.com is still broken for everyone not using Firefox. Here's [the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website/+bug/614590). The best way to get that on the radar is to click on "Does this bug affect you?" and select yes! (Please don't comment spam the bug)

Did I miss anything?

Comment: What kind of promotion from the Ubuntu team/release cycle could we expect with the going public of this site?

Answer (score 7):

Launching on 10.10.10 will only see our announcement overshadowed by the Ubuntu release itself. I don't think the date matters...

All the things you talk about in your 'question' sound really exciting though!

Comment: That is a good point. Unless we can get the release team to highlight it somewhere "officially" (even if we can't get ask.ubuntu.com)

Comment: I think we can ride the wave of the release actually. It'll be up to all of us to ensure we're mentioning the site in places where people are talking about 10.10.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to get your votes in for the [Captcha](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/84) and [404](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/32) image nominations. These things need to be decided on soon.

Also, I'm going to make sure [my tools](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/75) get updated and everything is in place for this. Any bug reports or suggestions need to be submited / added soon.

Answer (score 2):

I like the launch idea for 10-10-10 very much !!!

Comment: I agree! An excellent idea