# Design Ideas for the final site

Tags: discussion, design

Hi everyone,

At the beginning of the beta I linked up Mat Tomaszewski from the [Canonical Design Team](http://design.canonical.com/theteam/) to work with Jin Yang from SO on the design for the final site. I am posting the design here on his behalf since he doesn't have the rep (yet!)

**Home page:**

[image]

**Question Page**

[image]

**Error Page**

(a little pun on the twitter's fail whale ;)

[image]

Comment: I knew Mat would do an amazing job, +42

Comment: Converted to Community Wiki

Comment: WOW! That really feels like part of the Ubuntu family, rather than part of the Stack Exchange family. Great job.

Comment: Gorgeousness and gorgeousity!

Comment: Design is nice, but dont you feel the font size is a notch high? It feels like I have zoomed in the page.

Comment: Also, wasn't this supposed to be used once we are out of beta?

Answer (score 7):

I can't think of a better suited person to design the SE Ubuntu site! Good job Mat, I love the design.

Answer (score 4):

The whole thing looks amazing.

One quick thing... were you able to secure the rights to use the [Penguin image](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/32/404-image-nominations/41#41) for the 404 page? That was pretty much a unanimous decision.

The vote on the [captcha image](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/84/help-select-a-captcha-image) question seemed to suggest that [this](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/84/help-select-a-captcha-image/97#97) image should be used.

Answer (score 2):

How will site-wide messages be displayed/handled (Like that at the top of the site now)?

Otherwise this site design looks absolutely spectacular! Great job Mat!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment Marco, glad you like the design! With regards to your question - we're yet to tackle this, but I think they will use the similar logic to the current notifications.

Comment: I wonder if they could look notify-osdish?

Comment: Probably not, since notify-osd is very "desktop" (also, the bubbles are non-actionable, unlike SE notifications). We're still in the process of defining the notification experience for the web, and until that's done I think we should follow the logic the SE users are familiar and comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

Awesome !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Simply Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like an option for a dark them. I can't stand to look at very bright colors.

Answer (score 0):

I love the design on this site and really digg the Ubuntu Font (i believe this is the same one used on the site correct?)

Answer (score -1):

can we stars on the browsing level of the questions without having to click into the question. Makes it easy to star questions, for later reading.

Great Job!

Comment: @garbadgecollector that's a feature which will impact all Stackoverflow trilogy/Stackexchange sites. you can request the feature at meta.stackoverflow.com