# Possibility of getting an Identi.ca button?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Share Link via identi.ca](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/919/share-link-via-identi-ca)

Like a lot of folks in the Ubuntu community, I have an [Identi.ca](http://identi.ca/) account but not a Twitter one. Is there intrest in getting an Identi.ca button alongside the Facebook and Twitter one? Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/919/18612

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Identi.ca **is** supported by [AddThis.com](http://www.addthis.com/) which is what all the share links on the frontpage (excluding email) are powered by, so I suspect it would be quite simple to do from a technical point of view.

However I'm not sure if the new design launching tomorrow includes these links anymore - they're not in the [design ideas](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/377/design-ideas-for-the-final-site) and other launched sites such as [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) don't have them.

Comment: You're right, I hadn't noticed that in the design proposal. Now that the new site is live, those links are no longer there.

Comment: Oh wait, they're back on questions, but not on meta.

Comment: There's no longer links on the homepage, but we do have Twitter and Facebook links down the left hand side on question pages.