# Share Link via identi.ca

Tags: feature-request, promote

I can share links for questions via mail, Twitter and Facebook. But what about identi.ca?

Comment: seems like the question is for that site: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is: It isn't set up that way. 
The long answer is: We (That is, AskUbuntu) can't add that feature because AskUbuntu.com uses the [StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com) software that powers [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com). So if you really want it, go ahead and email the StackExchange team over at team@stackoverflow.com

Comment: i emailed them but very little suspect very little chances for adding identi.ca support.

Comment: Good luck - I'd probably use identi.ca more if I could share this with a button.

Answer (score 3):

I’ve tried to create such a button (not for Stack Exhange, but for other sites). It didn’t work well, because Identi.ca itself was not set up to let it work well.

- If you happen to be signed into Identi.ca, it does work, albeit a little clunkily.
- If you’re not, what you’d expect is a login/signup screen, and once you’re logged in or signed up, you’d expect a “post message” screen with the link text already there in the message. That’s not what you get. What you get is an incomprehensible error message. Not helpful. I don’t expect Stack Exhcange to add “Share on Identi.ca” buttons till Identi.ca themselves tidy up a bit.

So push Identi.ca first, then come back to pushing Stack Exchange.

Things may have changed: maybe, when you talk to Identi.ca, you’ll find that they’ve already fixed this problem. If so, please do let me know.