# Allow answers to be shared on Identi.ca

Tags: feature-request, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Share Link via identi.ca](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/919/share-link-via-identi-ca)

I've noticed that your own answers on AskUbuntu can be shared via Facebook and Twitter currently:

[image: Current sharing options]

However, some of us might prefer not to sign our souls over to evil corporate overlords, but rather go with a more open solution. Is there any chance a sharing option for [Identi.ca](http://identi.ca/) could be added in addition to these?