# Unaligned Borders

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Just noticed the unaligned borders in the navigation bar of the website.

In Firefox:

[image]

Also in Chrome:

[image]

I don't know if this question fits in meta askubuntu, but is it a bug or just a style?

Comment: Can confirm. Doesn't happen on the meta though.

Comment: Confirmed on main. Not on meta

Comment: yep, same. I wonder what changed.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I need to accept an answer or not.

Comment: @green7 In case of bug reports, you'd usually accept the answer of a dev stating they fixed it.

Comment: Seems it's fixed.

Comment: There are still some issues which I notice. Should I open this question again or ask a new question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I updated the divider borders using CSS only last night, but the updated background image(without borders) didn't get updated due to caching. It will be fixed after our next production build.

I had to implement the borders as part of the image before because I wanted to stay true to Canonical's [designer's work.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/377/design-ideas-for-the-final-site) At the time when the design launched, I didn't feel comfortable using rgba() due to browser support at the time.

Comment: Remember that you don't have to support any version of IE with us ;)

Comment: The border on the right of `Unanswered` is absent while it is present in meta site.

Comment: @Oli music to my ears

Answer (score 2):

## Technically, it's bydesign.

*But really, it's just godawfuldesign.*

The bright borders are part of the background:

[image]

The dark borders, on the other hand, are defined in the CSS:

```
.nav li {
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(160, 50, 10, 0.3);
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

These don't align properly (yay boxmodel, random changes and stuff like that) and as such, this bug occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe we can just nix the Background borders.

And Move the Ask Question into the navigation, Since they will be fixing other parts of the design as well...

[image]

Notice that a line was added in-front of "Ask Question" that looks like a divider meant for the top bar:

[image]

Here is a version of the background without the lines,

[image]

Do you think it had anything to do with adding the bar for new users?
Makes the extra space look even worse.

[image]

And finally what it looks like without the background lines:

[image]